# Automating opening Excel workbook and running macros on Linux Wine

Tags: python, excel, linux, automation, wine

I am running Excel 2016 on Wine. I have a workbook with some macros that i need to run at 9pm everyday. So i want to automate opening the workbook in Excel and running the macros. On Windows, i could use Task Scheduler. Unfortunately there is no Windows Task Scheduler in Wine so I can't figure out a way to do this.

I also tried to manipulate the workbook using Python and xlwings, win32com.client, etc, but those only work on Windows.

Any ideas for how I could accomplish this?